# Converting a symbol into a numeric figure

Tags: matlab

This coding is from MATLAB. So, I have 3 equations and I made three unknowns but when I tried to solve for the unknowns, they just come up as [1x1 sym], I tried so many stuff like double or vpa but it still doesn't work. Please help guys, thank you in advance. Here's my code until now.

```
h=3.5;         % height in meter
m=20;          % mass of traffic light in kg

W=m*9.81;              %Weight of the traffic light


Bx=3;
By=4;
Bz=(4-h);
Cx=-6;
Cy=-3;
Cz=(6-h);
Dx=4;
Dy=-3;
Dz=(4-h);

AB=[Bx By Bz];     %Position vector of AB
AC=[Cx Cy Cz];     %Position vector of AC
AD=[Dx Dy Dz];     %Position vector of AD

Mag_AB= sqrt(Bx^2+By^2+Bz^2);        %Magnitude of AB
Mag_AC= sqrt(Cx^2+Cy^2+Cz^2);        %Magnitude of AC
Mag_AD= sqrt(Dx^2+Dy^2+Dz^2);        %Magnitude of AD

u_AB= AB/Mag_AB;  %Unit vector of AB
u_AC= AC/Mag_AC;  %Unit Vector of AC
u_AD= AD/Mag_AD;  %Unit vector of AD
u_W=[0 0 -1];

syms B C D
eq1=(u_AB(1)*B+u_AC(1)*C+u_AD(1)*D);
eq2=(u_AB(2)*B+u_AC(2)*C+u_AD(2)*D);
eq3=(u_AB(3)*B+u_AC(3)*C+u_AD(3)*D)-u_W(1)*W;

sol=solve(eq1,eq2,eq3,B,C,D)
```

The answer it gave me was
    sol =

```
B: [1x1 sym]
C: [1x1 sym]
D: [1x1 sym]
```

Comment: It doesn't look as C /C++ code

Comment: You are seeing a `struct` representation which will display like you've shown for objects. You'll want to access each element (`B = sol.B`) and now if you display this you'll see the number you're expecting `disp(sol.B)`

Comment: This is explained in the documentation for `solve`.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be solving for these equations symbolically. It looks like a set of [homogeneous equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems), so the result is trivial (all zero) for B C and D when you solve with the symbolic equations. You can use the `svd` function to get the eigenvalues and solve for a homogeneous set of equations. In your case, this would be

```
A = [u_AB' u_AC' u_AD'];
[u, s, v] = svd(A);

B = v(1, end);
C = v(2, end);
D = v(3, end);

residuals = A * v(:, end);
```

However, I'd be careful about how you've set up your equations. Especially the `-u_W(1)*W` term in `eq3`. Did you mean `-u_W(3)*W`? If so, you'd have to add that term to the `A` matrix above. Anyways, I hope it all works out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, where is your equation really?
   how to solve `(u_AB(1)*B+u_AC(1)*C+u_AD(1)*D)`?

You need to use it this way, for example:

```
eq1 = (u_AB(1)*B+u_AC(1)*C+u_AD(1)*D) == 1;
```

Now it's equation.

2. Why you can't see result:

   ```
   eq1  = (6*101^(1/2)*B)/101 - (12*205^(1/2)*C)/205 + (8*101^(1/2)*D)/101 == 1
   s = solve(eq1, B,C,D)
   s.B
   ```

   and get this:

   ```
   ans =

   101^(1/2)/6
   ```

   Read more about this here [solve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html)